# Wordpress sending variable from backend function to frontend

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

In Wordpress childtheme functions.php I have simple function for adding two numbers.

```
function add_two_numbers($numa, $numb) {
    $numc = $numa + $numb;
    return $numc;
}
```

then I have action for Contact Form 7 where I want to process numbers filled in that form on frontend (two number fields and submit button).

Now I want to show result of adding two numbers on my frontend page in the html snippet (ideally). How do I get it?

I've tried to add action for contact form 7, but I haven't find solution to acces variable result on frontend

```
// Contact form 7 Webhook
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "process_variable");
function process_variable($contact_form) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        $numa = (int) $posted_data['number_a'];
        $numb = (int) $posted_data['number_b'];
        $result = add_two_numbers($numa, $numb);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data in wp-options table.

Use `update_option` and `get_option` to update and fetch the value.

```
<?php 
update_option( 'prefix_two_numbers_sum', 25 ); // Assuming sum is 25
?>
```

Then you can retrieve the value in the frontend.

```
<?php echo get_option( 'prefix_two_numbers_sum' ); ?>
```

Doc: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/

`add_option` is used to add the value if not exists. I do recommend you to test with `update_option`

Some helpful conversation on when to use `add_option` and `update_option` : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71420/add-option-if-not-exists

Advance level: You may consider checking autoload (3rd parameter of `update_option`) to optimise your site.